# how to make scrollbar start at the bottom?

Tags: java, scroll, jframe, jtextarea, jscrollbar

I'm creating a java chat application using jFrame. I'm using a JScrollPane to scroll the text area. All the new messages are added at the bottom, but the scroll bar starts at the top. How do I make it start at the bottom?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set AUTO-SCROLLING of JTextArea in Java GUI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627028/how-to-set-auto-scrolling-of-jtextarea-in-java-gui)

Answer (score 1):

You can force it to scroll to the bottom after adding a message by scrolling its vertical scrollbar directly, e.g.:

```
JScrollBar vScrollBar = myScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
vScrollBar.setValue(vScrollBar.getMaximum());
```